# Regex for getting javascript functions in C#.net

Tags: c#, regex

I use webBrowser.DocumentText to get the html code of a page.
using Regex, i manage to get the script tag part.
< script type="text/javascript">functions here..< /script> 

I need to get functions inside those tags.
ex.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function function1 () { code here;}
 function function2 () { code here;} 
<br>
</script>
```

I need regex pattern to get the 2 functions 
 or list them down like this
1. function funtion1() { code here; }
2. function funtion2() { code here; }

purpose of the program is to identify if there's a duplicate javascript functions between 
2 pages.

Its for winForms and language is C#

Comment: ... these <script> elements are in more HTML?

Then you shouldn't be doing this RegEx. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific, you want the entire function, the function names?  Also, your example...those aren't even valid javascript functions, they have no names...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do it in any general way with regexes alone (especially not with the .NET flavour), since JavaScript scopes can be nested arbitrarily deeply and the language is therefore irregular. If you need them for a few particular pages, you might be able to craft a regex that handles common cases, but not all.

Answer (score 0):

```
e = ".*?(function.+?{.*?}|\\z)";
repl = "\\1";
```

I believe that's it.

Comment: but is it possible for nested "}"?

Comment: In Javascript, yes.  I was assuming the standard syntax.

Comment: But you can't have nested <script tags, so you could just return the content of <script>...</script>

Comment: e = ".*?(<script.*?>(.*?)</script>|\\z)"; repl = "\\2"; But that will leave in any var statements so you could make a second pass to remove anything starting with var and ending with \n. Also I didn't account for spaces in between the starting '<' and script (etc.) for readability